# Terminal doesn't open after doing "screenfetch"

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, gnome-terminal

My problem is: I can't launch terminal in **any** way after using [screenfetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch). Term is looking like opening, cursor changes, but no window appears. I'm using Kali Linux 2.0 Rolling.

**Ways to reproduce the issue**:

1. Download *screenfetch* via *apt* - "*apt install screenfetch*"
2. Type *screenfetch* in terminal
3. Close the terminal
4. Try to open it again - don't works

The only way to fix it - reboot, but anyway this shouldn't appear, and I can't find out why this is happening. What should I do?